# xbindkeys not working when native Gnome 3.30.1 windows are focused

Tags: gnome, windows, gnome3, gnome-shell, xbindkeys

this is archlinux speaking, fresh install with Gnome 3.30.1.

After having installed `xbindkeys` and setup a `~/.xbindkeysrc` file with:

```
# corresponds to ctrl+Y on my machine, according to `xbindkeys -k`
"paplay /usr/share/sounds/gnome/default/alerts/sonar.ogg"
  m:0x14 + c:52
```

I can hit `ctrl+Y` and hear a sonar sound. But **only** if the current window is:

- firefox
- vlc
- zotero
- ..

but **not** if the current window is:

- gnome-terminal
- nautilus
- gnome "web" application
- gnome "system-monitor"
- ...

What is wrong?
Is gnome somehow capturing the events before `xbindkeys`? Why?
How to prevent it from doing so, so I get consistent behaviour accross all windows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I get it. The bug only occurs if you log on Gnome `wayland` session, which happens to be the default one now. Should you **log with Gnome `Xorg` instead**, the bindings do work with every window then.

My guess is that `xbindkeys` is a X-related utility, that every new Gnome app do not rely on X anymore but on `wayland`, and that firefox, vlc, *etc.* still rely on X, therefore the bindings only working with them. Is that correct?